# Filtering using __range on a datetimefield

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-views, jinja2

I have read and try so many tactics to make __range inclusive. Please can someone help out here

views.py

```
def generate_report(request):

    if 'start_date' and 'end_date' in request.GET:
        account_type = AccountUser.objects.get(user_id=request.user.id)

        query_string_start = request.GET.get('start_date')
        query_string_end = request.GET.get('end_date')


        search_query = BedAllotment.objects.filter(hospital_id=account_type.hospital_id,
                                                   departure_date__gte=query_string_start, departure_date__lte=query_string_end).order_by('-departure_date')

        return render (request, 'report/report_preview.html', {'account_type':account_type, 'query_data':search_query,
                                                               'query_string_start': query_string_start,
                                                               'query_string_end':query_string_end})
```

models.py

```
class BedAllotment(models.Model):
    BILL_TO = (
        ('self', 'Self'),
        ('insurance', 'Insurance')
    )
    PAYMENT_MODE = (
        ('cash', 'Cash'),
        ('cheque', 'Cheque'),
        ('transfer', 'Transfer'),
        ('pos', 'POS'),
    )

    hospital = models.ForeignKey(Hospital)
    patient = models.ForeignKey(PatientProfile)
    bed = models.ForeignKey(BedCreate)
    allotment_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    departure_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    days = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=False)
    amount = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=False)
    amount_paid = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=False)
    discount = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=False)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I will like to include all query instance on the end_date. Please Help

Comment: Can you share the model. What is the `departure_date`? A `DateField` or `DateTimeField`? What are possible values of `start_date`, and `end_date`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem question updated with models.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand it correctly `depart_date` is a `DateTimeField`. Now say that the date time is `2018-08-21 12:34`, then that is *larger* than `2018-08-21`, since by default a date is assumed to have as time `00:00`.

We can use the `__date` lookup however, like:

```
search_query = BedAllotment.objects.filter(
    hospital_id=account_type.hospital_id,
    departure_date__date__range=(query_string_start, query_string_end)
).order_by('-departure_date')
```

This means that we thus first "convert" the `departure_date` to the equivalent `DateField` value, and then we check if it is in the range.

Note that date/time is complicated: the date depends on the timezone, and thus if the `query_string_start`, etc. are in *another* timezone, the math might not be sound. So it is possible you need to do some "pre-processing" on the parameters you obtain.